# Javascript - Cannot set property 'src' of null at HTMLButtonElement

Tags: javascript

The error is this one;

> app.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
>       at HTMLButtonElement.

This is the code(javascript):

```
const playerHand = document.querySelector('player-hand')
playerHand.src = `assets/${this.textContent}.png`;
```

this is the html

```
<img class="player-hand" src="assets/rock.png" alt="">
```

Comment: You need to show more code, including how you're setting `playerHand`.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: What is the value of `playerHand` just before we do `playerHand.src` ?

Comment: const playerHand = document.querySelector('player-hand')

Comment: <img class="player-hand" src="assets/rock.png" alt=""> This is Html

Comment: I've tryed to find a solution for ever, but i don't know what Im doing wrong

Comment: what is `this.textContent`?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change

```
const playerHand = document.querySelector('player-hand')
```

By

```
const playerHand = document.querySelector('.player-hand')
```

Or put this is in the IMG element

Comment: Or maybe it should be `#player-hand`.

Comment: @Barmar the OP has posted in the comments that the element is an `img` with a class of `player-hand`

Comment: I dint't see that  missinig dot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the path to the image like this.

```
playerHand.src = './assets/'+this.textContent+'.png';
```